# Why calling setState in a callback inside child widget, which have another setState, breaks program?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Here is a custom Switch widget I implemented using Animation.

```dart
enum SwitchType {
  LockToggle, EnableToggle
}

class DiamondSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final double width, height;
  final SwitchType switchType;
  final double switchThumbSize;
  final VoidCallback onTapCallback;

  DiamondSwitch({
    key, this.width, this.height,
    this.switchType, this.switchThumbSize,
    @required this.onTapCallback
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DiamondSwitchState createState() => _DiamondSwitchState(
    width: width, height: height,
    switchType: switchType, switchThumbSize: switchThumbSize,
    onTapCallback: onTapCallback
  );
}

class _DiamondSwitchState extends State<DiamondSwitch> {
  final double width, height;
  final int _toggleAnimationDuration = 1000;

  bool _isOn = false;

  final List<Color>
    _darkGradientShades = <Color>[
      Colors.black, Color.fromRGBO(10, 10, 10, 1.0)
    ],
    _lightGradientShades = <Color>[
      Colors.white, Color.fromRGBO(150, 150, 150, 1.0)
    ];

  final SwitchType switchType;

  final double switchThumbSize;

  List<Icon> _switchIcons = new List<Icon>();
  final double _switchIconSize = 35.0;

  final VoidCallback onTapCallback;

  _DiamondSwitchState({
    this.width = 100.0, this.height = 40.0,
    this.switchThumbSize = 40.0, @required this.switchType,
    @required this.onTapCallback
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    _switchIcons.addAll(
      (switchType == SwitchType.LockToggle)?
        <Icon>[
          Icon(
            Icons.lock,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: _switchIconSize,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.lock_open,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: _switchIconSize,
          )
        ]
      :
        <Icon>[
          Icon(
            Icons.done,
            color: Colors.black,
            size: _switchIconSize,
          ),
          Icon(
            Icons.close,
            color: Colors.white,
            size: _switchIconSize,
          )
        ]
    );
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: _toggleAnimationDuration),
      width: width, height: height,
      decoration: ShapeDecoration(
        shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28.0),
          side: (_isOn)?
              BorderSide(
                color: Color.fromRGBO(45, 45, 45, 1.0),
                width: 0.5,
              )
            :
              BorderSide.none,
        ),
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: <Color>[
            ...((_isOn)? _darkGradientShades : _lightGradientShades)
          ],
          begin: Alignment(1.0, -0.8), end: Alignment(-0.7, 1.0),
          stops: <double>[0.4, 1.0]
        ),
      ),
      alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment(0.0, 0.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedPositioned(
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: _toggleAnimationDuration),
            curve: Curves.easeIn,
            left: (_isOn)? 0.0 : ((width * 70) / 100),
            right: (_isOn)? ((width * 70) / 100) : 0.0,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                onTapCallback();
                setState(() {
                  _isOn = !_isOn;
                });
              },
              child: AnimatedSwitcher(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: _toggleAnimationDuration),
                transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
                  return FadeTransition(
                    opacity: animation,
                    child: child,
                  );
                },
                child: Transform.rotate(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  angle: (math.pi / 4),
                  child: Container(
                    width: switchThumbSize, height: switchThumbSize,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(3.0),
                      color: (_isOn)? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                      border: (_isOn)?
                        null
                      :
                        Border.all(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(87, 87, 87, 1.0),
                          width: 1.0,
                        ),
                    ),
                    child: Transform.rotate(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      angle: -(math.pi / 4),
                      child: (_isOn)?
                        _switchIcons[0]
                      :
                        _switchIcons[1],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I added a onTapCallback because I need to set another flag in the parent widget to trigger a Image change. Here is related code that belongs to parent widget;

```dart
DiamondSwitch(
  switchType: SwitchType.LockToggle,
  width: 186.0,
  height: 60.0,
  switchThumbSize: 41.0,
  onTapCallback: () {
    this.setState(() {
      this._isLockOn = !this._isLockOn;
    });
  },
  key: UniqueKey(),
),
```

When I run this code, animation doesn't work. It detects tap and executes *onTap* callback, and all code in *onTap* Works, (I tested with *print* methods), but as I said, animation isn't happening.

I want to learn why does this happen, is this about how Flutter work? If yes, can you explain?

TY for taking time ^.^!

---

**EDIT**

I want to know why does getting a method with setState breaks the animation I'm sharing the current parent widget with the approach of the answerer @pulyaevskiy implemented.

```dart
class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {
  bool
    _isLockOn = false,
    _isPassiconOn = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            /*Lock Toggle Graphic*/
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(-0.1, 0.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  /*Lock Toggle Text*/
                  RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          (_isLockOn)? "locked" : "unlocked",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: "Philosopher",
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            shadows: <Shadow>[
                              Shadow(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(184, 184, 184, 0.68),
                                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                blurRadius: 4.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.5),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(204, 204, 204, 1.0),
                            width: 30.0, height: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*Lock Toggle Image*/
                  Image.asset(
                    "assets/images/settings_screen/crystal_"
                        "${(_isLockOn)? "white_light_up" : "black_outline"}.png",
                    scale: 5.0,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            /*Lock Toggle Switch*/
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.5),
              child: DiamondSwitch(
                switchType: SwitchType.LockToggle,
                width: 186.0,
                height: 60.0,
                switchThumbSize: 41.0,
                flagToControl: this._isLockOn,
                onTapCallback: () {
                  this.setState(() {
                    this._isLockOn = !this._isLockOn;
                  });
                },
                key: UniqueKey(),
              ),
            ),
            /*Separator*/
            WhiteDiamondSeparator(paddingAmount: 36.5),
            /*Passicon Toggle Graphic*/
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(-0.32, 0.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: <Widget>[
                  /*Lock Toggle Text*/
                  RotatedBox(
                    quarterTurns: 3,
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "passicon",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontFamily: "Philosopher",
                            fontSize: 25.0,
                            shadows: <Shadow>[
                              Shadow(
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(184, 184, 184, 0.68),
                                offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                                blurRadius: 4.0,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.5),
                          child: Container(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(204, 204, 204, 1.0),
                            width: 30.0, height: 1.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  /*Passicon Toggle Image*/
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/settings_screen/emote_"
                          "${(_isPassiconOn)? "winking" : "nervous"}.png",
                      scale: 3.25,
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            /*Passicon Toggle Switch*/
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 42.5),
              child: DiamondSwitch(
                switchType: SwitchType.PassiconToggle,
                width: 186.0,
                height: 60.0,
                switchThumbSize: 41.0,
                flagToControl: this._isPassiconOn,
                onTapCallback: () {
                  this.setState(() {
                    this._isPassiconOn = !this._isPassiconOn;
                  });
                },
                key: UniqueKey(),
              ),
            ),
            /*Separator*/
            WhiteDiamondSeparator(paddingAmount: 36.5),
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And I added `flagToControl` in `DiamondSwitch` and using it in `_DiamondSwitchState` as `bool get _isOn => widget.flagToControl;`.

In the old approach, if I don't execute and other thing than

```dart
setState() { _isOn = !_isOn; }
```

animation happens as it should. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In your `onTapCallback` you are changing state of your parent widget, which works indeed. However it does not affect state of the `DiamondSwitch` widget itself 
(I see that in GestureDetector you also setState of the switch widget, but there are a few issues with this approach).

To fix this you can pass the value of `this._isLockOn` from your parent widget's state to the `DiamondSwitch` child. This means you need another property on your switch widget. E.g.

```dart
class DiamondSwitch extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isOn;
  // ... remaining fields go here
  DiamondSwitch({this.isOn, ...});
}
```

Then change `_DiamondSwitchState` as well. Could simply proxy `_isOn` to the widget's value:

```dart
class _DiamondSwitchState extends State<DiamondSwitch> {
  bool get _isOn => widget.isOn;
}
```

This is much better than keeping state of `isOn` in two places as you have now (in parent widget AND in the switch itself). With this change your `isLockOn` state is only kept on the parent widget and you just pass it down to the switch child to use.

This means that for GestureDetector's `onTap` property you'll simply pass the `onTapCallback` of the parent widget as well, no need to wrap it with another function.

The last part: in your parent widget's build method:

```dart
DiamondSwitch(
  isOn: this._isLockOn, // <-- new line here to pass the value down
  switchType: SwitchType.LockToggle,
  width: 186.0,
  height: 60.0,
  switchThumbSize: 41.0,
  onTapCallback: () {
    this.setState(() {
      this._isLockOn = !this._isLockOn;
    });
  },
  key: UniqueKey(),
),
```

Another benefit of doing it this way is that now you can initialize your switch with a different default value if needed (right now it's hardcoded to always start off as `false`). So if you load value of `isLockOn` from a database and it's set to `true` you can immediately pass this value to the switch child and represent your state correctly.

Comment: I liked your approach, however, I noticed transition _still_ isn't working as they should be. I use `_isLockOn` flag to change an Image on parent widget. When I used my old approach, at first time I press on DiamondSwitch widget, whole screen was getting re-builded; this part is still same, but it only happens at first touch. None of the transitions were working at all, now, transitions happen instantly. Do you want me to edit my post to include parent widget too, if this helps? I really want to understand what is going on.